# Does multiple tensioning pulley affects the belt speed?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, speed

Consider a multiple pulley system with the main pulley(30mm) attached to the motor shaft and multiple tensioning pulley in different locations(all are 15mm), driven pulley of 15mm is connected to the belt.

The main pulley is 60rpm.

Can I safely assume that the final pulley attached to conveyor belt is 120rpm?(since the driven pulley is smaller than the main pulley by half). Considering no slip condition.

Or I need to do a more complex calculation like involving belt tension and so forth?

Comment: Its not so simple if the pitch diameters are different

Comment: @QuIcKmAtHs both the pulley and belt is not teethed, then is my deduction correct?

Comment: not  really, i dont think that affects